# WebSockets : Getting Safari to work with pywebsockets Apache extension

Tags: safari, websocket

I am trying to get WebSocket running on an Apache server with the help of pywebsocket.
 The server is now setup and I am able to make a Websocket connection through Chrome. However, when I try to make a connection through Safari I am getting a **"Unexpected response code: 404"** and it doesn't appear that the WebSocket connection is able to be established with the server.

Any pointers here would be appreciated. Below is the client side JS code I am invoking to make a connection and the safari header tags vs the Chrome header tags.

```
    function connect() {
        if ('WebSocket' in window) {
            socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost/mystream");
        } else if ('MozWebSocket' in window) {
            socket = new MozWebSocket("ws://localhost/mystream");
        } else {
            return;
        }

    socket.onopen = function () {
        showResult('Opened');
    };
    socket.onmessage = function (event) {
        showResult(event.data);
    };
    socket.onerror = function () {
        showResult('Error in connection');
    };
    socket.onclose = function (event) {
        var logMessage = 'Closed (';
        if ((arguments.length == 1) && ('CloseEvent' in window) && (event instanceof CloseEvent)) {
            logMessage += 'wasClean = ' + event.wasClean;
            if ('code' in event) {
                logMessage += ', code = ' + event.code;
            }
            if ('reason' in event) {
                logMessage += ', reason = ' + event.reason;
            }
        } else {
            logMessage += 'CloseEvent is not available';
        }
        showResult(logMessage + ')');
  };

  showResult('Successfully Connected ');
}
```

**Safari Headers :**

```
Origin: http://192.168.1.8
Sec-WebSocket-Key1: 26 ~ 5 75G3 36< 0 U8T
Connection: Upgrade
Host: localhost
Sec-WebSocket-Key2: 1<A   9 4 4l865P5/6L5
Upgrade: WebSocket
```

**Chrome Headers :**

```
Connection:Upgrade
Host:localhost
Origin:http://192.168.1.8
Sec-WebSocket-Key:IAkX9XGWsCZHPQepzYjwxA==
Sec-WebSocket-Version:13
Upgrade:websocket
(Key3):00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get it working now. Safari (5.1) and mobile safari both require the Hixie-75 flag which has experimental support in pywebsockets. The issue was with the entry in the apache conf file, the entry is supposed to be in all lowercase (i.e **on**) but the sample entry had it in CamelCase (**On**) . Reverting to all lowercase has solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

Those Safari headers are for an older revision of the protocol: Hixie-76. Hixie-76 is a lot less friendly to integration with web servers because there is special data (key3) sent after the headers. I suspect Safari will be updated to the newer version of the protocol (HyBi) in the next release or two.

The HyBi-76 handshake happens in [handshake/hybi00.py](http://www.google.com/codesearch#qXZjLxiexwM/trunk/src/mod_pywebsocket/handshake/hybi00.py&type=cs) You might try adding some debug to try and figure out where it is failing. In particular make sure that _get_challenge is actually getting the final 8 bytes (key3) of the challenge that are sent after the headers (this is the part that makes it complicated to handle Hixie-76 in a web server).

Comment: As per the documentation on the pywebsockets site Hixie-76 seems to be supported in the list of websocket protocol implementations.

Comment: Yes, Hixie-76 is definitely supported by pywebsockets. But pywebsockets has two modes: standalone and mod_python. It's the second mode that is tricky with Hixie-76. You might also try running pywebsockets standalone for comparison.

Comment: Managed to get it working now. Safari (5.1) and mobile safari both require Hixie-75 which has experimental support in pywebsockets. The issue was with the entry in the apache conf file, it is supposed to be in all lowercase but the sample entry had it in CamelCase.